# Anno1404 2nd mission in campaign: How to deliver fish and cider

Tags: anno-1404

In Anno 1404, in the second mission of the campaign,  you are asked to deliver 15t fish and 3t to Guy Forcas,  but after loading these supplies on my ship and reaching the port of Forcas(Twickham) ,  I find that I cannot unload these from my ship,  even though I am in range,  as it keeps saying 'no suitable territory found'. How do I deliver the supplies to Forcas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for such delivery quests, you do not need to unload items from your ship, and trying to do so may end up selling them to the NPC instead of completing the quest. Once you sail your ship near the relevant port or island, you should get a pop-up of the NPC asking if you're ready to hand over the items.

From your description though, it sounds like you're doing everything right.

You can also look at this [wiki page](http://anno1404.wikia.com/wiki/In_the_Sign_of_the_Cross#Finishing_the_quest:_Supply_the_Crusader_army) for hints on what you might be doing wrong.